# Javascript FullCalendar refetchEvents V5 after modal close

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm converting a V4 fullcalendar to V5 and the code I used to refetch the events after the modal closes no longer works.  The code was

```
$('#fullCalModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
});
```

The documentation just say this

```
calendar.refetchEvents()
```

But it has no reference to calendar, it just says "calendar.refetchEvents is not a function"

I've been googling and trying things all afternoon with no luck, so any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FullCalendar V5 changed the initialization completely, so you need to implement v5 like below-

```
var calendar;
      $(document).ready(function () {
        // new way to init full calendar in v5
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        // store calendar reference in global variable like below so you can use it later.
        calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
        });
        calendar.render();
      });
      // so your code will be
      $('#fullCalModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        calendar.refetchEvents();
      });
```

Comment: I'm an idiot (and new at Javascript!)  I was initialising it very similarly to you but creating the calendar var when creating the calendar, so not making it global.  I moved it outside and now all is fine.  Thanks SO much for the nudge in the right direction.